# The second JFrame is blank and very small

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm new to Swing and I'm having trouble replacing an existing JFrame. I initialize the first JFrame without a problem.

class GererAdgerent :

```
public class GererAdherent extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
static GererAdherent frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new GererAdherent();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GererAdherent() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnAjouterAdherent = new JButton("Ajouter Adherent");
    btnAjouterAdherent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            AjouterAdherent ajouterAdherent = new AjouterAdherent();
            ajouterAdherent.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnAjouterAdherent.setBounds(104, 34, 130, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnAjouterAdherent);
}

}
```

But once I try to initialize a different JFRame, I get a blank JFrame without all of it's components (It is created properly when I use AjouterAdherent's main to initialize)

class AjouterAdherent :

```
public class AjouterAdherent extends JFrame {

JFrame frame;
JTextField txtNom;

static Properties p=new Properties();
static BibliothequeDAORemote proxy;
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException  {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AjouterAdherent window = new AjouterAdherent();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public AjouterAdherent() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JTextPane txtpnAjouterClient = new JTextPane();
    txtpnAjouterClient.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    txtpnAjouterClient.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
    txtpnAjouterClient.setEnabled(false);
    txtpnAjouterClient.setEditable(false);
    txtpnAjouterClient.setForeground(Color.black);
    txtpnAjouterClient.setBounds(175, 11, 89, 20);
    txtpnAjouterClient.setText("Ajouter Client");
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtpnAjouterClient);

    JTextPane txtpnNom = new JTextPane();
    txtpnNom.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
    txtpnNom.setEnabled(false);
    txtpnNom.setEditable(false);
    txtpnNom.setForeground(Color.black);
    txtpnNom.setBounds(36, 49, 72, 20);
    txtpnNom.setText("Nom");
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtpnNom);


}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

> (It is created properly when I use AjouterAdherent's main to initialize)

So look at the code that works properly:

```
AjouterAdherent window = new AjouterAdherent();
window.frame.setVisible(true);
```

> I try to initialize a different JFRame, I get a blank JFrame

And look at the code that doesn't work:

```
AjouterAdherent ajouterAdherent = new AjouterAdherent();
ajouterAdherent.setVisible(true);
```

What is the difference?

The problem is your class extends JFrame and also creates a new JFrame, so you have two frame instances, one with components and one without.

Don't extend JFrame! Then you won't cause confusion.

You should only extend a class when you add new functionality to the class. Adding components to the frame is not adding new functionality.